# How to run different functions in different parts of a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, covariance, variance

I have a dataframe(df).
I need to find the standard deviation dataframe from this one.For the first row I want to use the traditional variance formula.

sum of the(x - x(mean))/n

and from second row(=i) I want to use the following formula

lamb*(variance of first row) + (1-lamb)* (first row of returns)^2

※by first row, I meant the previous row.

```
# Generate Sample Dataframe

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.Dataframe({'a':range(1,7),
                 'b':[x**2 for x in range(1,7)],
                 'c':[x**3 for x in range(1,7)]})
```

```
# Generate return Dataframe

returns=df.pct_change()
```

```
# Generate new Zero dataframe

d=pd.DataFrame(0,index=np.arange(len(returns)),columns=returns.columns)

#populate first row
lamb=0.94
d.iloc[0]=list(returns.var())
```

Now my question is how to populated the second row till the end using the second formula?

It should be something like

```
d[1:].agg(lambda x: lamb*x.shift(-1)+(1-lamb)*returns[:2]
```

but it obviously returned a long error.
Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,len(d)):
    d.iloc[i].apply(lambda x: lamb*d.iloc[i-1] + (1-lamb)*returns.iloc[i-1])
```

I'm not completely sure if this gives the right answer but it wont throw an error. But try using apply, for loop and .iloc for iterating over rows and this should do the job for you if you use the correct formula.

Comment: Thank you. there is no error, but I only have zero for all the elements from first row till end. As my first row in "returns" is NaN the last part of the formula should be returns.iloc[i]    however still have Zero all over